When sending data to the backend, it's get's detected but not registered. However the backend doesn't show an error while the front does
I am working on a web project using nextJS as front and nestJS as back. I have a form page that gets filled with data, then that data is sent to the backend to be saved in the database.
Here is the form page :

The code :
const onSubmit = async (data) => {
    try {
      const formDataToSubmit = new FormData();
      Object.entries(data).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        formDataToSubmit.append(key, value);
      });
      formDataToSubmit.append("roles", JSON.stringify(Object.keys(roles).filter(role => roles[role])));
      if (profilePicture) {
        formDataToSubmit.append("profilePicture", profilePicture);
      }

      // Log form data for debugging
      console.log("Form Data Entries:", [...formDataToSubmit.entries()]);

      const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/register", formDataToSubmit, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        reset();
        router.push("/login");
      } else {
        console.error("Registration failed");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during registration:", error.message);
      if (error.response) {
        console.error("Error response data:", error.response.data);
        console.error("Error response status:", error.response.status);
        console.error("Error response headers:", error.response.headers);

        try {
          console.log("Raw response data:", error.response.data);
          JSON.parse(error.response.data);
        } catch (jsonError) {
          console.error("Invalid JSON response:", jsonError.message);
        }
      } else if (error.request) {
        console.error("Error request data:", error.request);
      } else {
        console.error("Error message:", error.message);
      }
      console.error("Error config:", error.config);
    }
  };

However, when I submit it, the data does end up at the back end but doesn't get registered and I get some errors at the front end level.
Here are some screenshots.
The backend result :

The errors :

Is there a problem with the front or the back? If so, can someone help me understand it and fix it?
I appreciate all the help that I could get.

This probably means that the backend expects some extra data that you are not including with your request or it's expecting a different form of some properties(e.g. expecting a number data type for the phone but you are sending a string), hence, you got 400 bad request.
